I have tried everything in Flask SQLAlchemy but it is still failing to create tables in Postgres
This is the code that I have written in my app.py file
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import os
import secrets
from modules.web_application.models.model import User, ScrapedData, PromptLog

load_dotenv()

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = os.getenv('DATABASE_URL')
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = secrets.token_hex(32)

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

try:
    with app.app_context():
        db.metadata.clear()
        print("Registered Tables:", db.metadata.tables.keys())
        db.create_all()
        print("Registered Tables:", db.metadata.tables.keys())

except Exception as e:
    print(f"Error during table creation: {e}")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)

I have tried clearing the db metadata, also tried db.create_all() in a 100 different ways. Please help me debug this

The db used to create your models must be the same db that you use to call db.create_all(); that is, the models are registered with a db, so that db must be used to create them.  Clearing the metadata is almost certainly a bad idea, but your db declarations are the problem.

Please share the error you get, that will help in guiding someone to help you properly.

@snakecharmerb it worked, thanks a lot
